# How to call a WCF Service methods on a test server (without VS2010) in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, simulate

i created a WCF service that also writes into a log file.
i put it On the IIS and run the SVC file to check if it runs ok and it does.

how do i simulate its methods? 
do i create another web site that calls its methods, and use the log file to trace its steps ?
can i install WCFTestClient on the test server ?

what is the best way to simulate wcf methods without a VS2010 installed ?

in asmx services you just "browse" the service and input the parameters in the service methods, can i do that in WCF methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install `WCFTestClient` on the server. You could use it from a remote machine to call the service. If your service uses an interoperable binding you could also take a look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Comment: i want to test the service from the test server itself, so i dont have access to a remote machine. HTTP GET i can test from the browser. and for Soap requests i'll try the link you suggested. thanks!